# PowerShell Script to Stop a service on multiple remote machines

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I am trying to disable a service running on 250+ PCs. I would like to have a PowerShell script I can execute on a random PC in the network and let it disable a service on every PC I specify in an txt file. It's always the same service. The script should also ask for the credential of the PC that it is trying to connect to.

This is a Script to set DNS on every PC in computer.txt. It asks me for the "administrator" password for every PC.

```
function Set-DNSWINS {
#Get NICS via WMI
$remoteuser = get-credential $_\administrator
$NICs = Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Credential $remoteuser -ComputerName $_ -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"
Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Credential $remoteuser -ComputerName $_ -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"

foreach($NIC in $NICs) {
$DNSServers = "192.168.3.12","192.168.0.77"
$NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)
$NIC.SetDynamicDNSRegistration("TRUE")
#$NIC.SetWINSServer("12.345.67.890", "12.345.67.891")
}
}

function Get-FileName {
$computer = Read-Host "Dateiname mit Computernamen"
return $computer
}

Get-Content computer.txt | ForEach-Object {Set-DNSWINS}
```

Comment: Are these machines part of the same domain? Do you have admin rights on all these PC's? Do all PC's run the same OS version? What version of PowerShell do they run?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop a service from the commandline using

```
net stop "servicename"
```

or in PowerShell

```
Stop-Service "serviceName"
```

There are probably better ways to automate this across multiple machines than your script.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `Set-Service` to disable a service and Invoke-Command to run it remotely. Note you need to run `Enable-PSRemoting` on the remote computer and configure WSMAN to allow connecting to the remote PC:

```
function MyFunction{
    $remoteuser = get-credential $_\administrator
    $service = "MyService"
    Invoke-Command -computer $_ -credential $remoteuser -scriptblock {
        Stop-Service $service
        Set-Service $service -startuptype Disabled
    }
}

function Get-FileName {
$computer = Read-Host "Dateiname mit Computernamen"
return $computer
}

Get-Content computer.txt | ForEach-Object {MyFunction}
```

Comment: This should not work as expected since you are calling `Set-Service` twice in different contexts. I would recommend against using the same name for your function as a preexisting cmdlet.

Comment: You're right, it was only something I threw together and didn't think, but semantics, it should work with a different name (have edited to something generic as inspiration is not with me today lol)

Comment: Powershell gives me these errors:The `Stop-Service` doesn't have the parameter computer. Also `Set-Service` doesn't have the parameter credential.

Comment: Ah. Well in that case you might have to use Invoke-Command which requires PSRemoting stuff be enabled, whether you want to do that. I'll update my answer, sorry I didn't look into that enough =/